# Trying to have the value attribute of a checkbox contain a php json_encode

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to get the value attribute of a checkbox control to contain the php json_encode() of a simpleXML object.

I've tried this for the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="select_comparable" value="<?php json_encode($comp); ?>">
```

I'm passing it to the controller with this jQuery:

```
    $("input[name^=select_]").on( "click", function(){
    alert($(this).data('value'))
    comp.simpleXML = $(this).val();
    selected.push(comp);
  });

  $("#btnSave").click(function(){
    //alert(selected[0]);

    $.ajax({
      url: "/comparable/save",
      type:"POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {"data": selected},
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.success) {
          alert("saved!");
        } else {
          alert("not saved!");
        }
      },
    });
  });
```

but when I look at my controller all I get is "{".

Comment: why would you ever need to json_encode a checkbox value? Should probably explain goals, likely come up with a far better approach

Comment: Did you try that with single quotes -> `value='<?php json_encode($comp); ?>'`

Comment: Thanks @adeneo! I also added echo so that it actually returned the value I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that JSON uses `"` a lot: strings and object property values are both enclosed in double quotes.

In order to put JSON in an HTML attribute, you MUST run it through `htmlspecialchars`.

You could have found the problem yourself if you used View Source ;)

Answer (score 0):

Posting @adeneo's comment as an answer. 
"Did you try that with single quotes -> value=''" –  adeneo